# How can I set a path for a file to upload if an <input> element is not visible and only reference by an anchor tag <a>?

Tags: javascript, webdriver, anchor, automated-tests

With WebDriver if the element is of type="file" I can usually just to a .sendKeys() directly to the element and it works beautifully.

Unfortunately the situation I have now there is a custom button used that has an anchor tag referring to the input element:

```
//anchor tag which is a custom button referring to non visible file input element
    <a id="image-upload-button" class="control_button button" href="#/create_channel/addImage" data-ember-action="151">

//refers to this file input element which is not visible
    <input id="image-selector-button" name="image-selector" type="file" class="selectImageBtn" {{action "selectImage" on="change" target="view"}} {{action "onBlur" on="blur" target="App.router.imageSelectorView"}} {{action "onFocus" on="focus" target="view"}}/>
```

In this case sendKeys() does not work on the anchor tag:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("image-upload-button ")).sendKeys(“c:\\myFile.bmp”);
```

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: focusElement execution failed; Failed to send keys because cannot focus element

Nor does sendKeys() work the non-visible file input element:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("image-selector-button ")).sendKeys(“c:\\myFile.bmp”);
```

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element must be displayed to click

I've tried injecting javaScript to set the path value on the non-visible input element a few different ways (see below), but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas on how I can set this path?

```
//nothing happens when I try this

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('image-selector-button').setAttribute('value','C:\\MyFile.jpg');");  



//I tried firing a change even first as well and that didn't appear to do anything either

js.executeScript(
"var el=document.getElementById('image-selector-button'); " +
" function fire(evttype) { " +
" if (document.createEvent) { " +
" var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents'); " +
" evt.initEvent( evttype, false, false); "+
" el.dispatchEvent(evt); " +
" } else if (document.createEventObject) { "+
"  el.fireEvent('on' + evttype); " +
" }    }; " +
" fire(el,'change'); " );
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's a very clear question if you have worked with Selenium WebDriver and a very good answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try displaying the control first, then set the value, then hide it again:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('image-selector-button').style.display = 'block';");
driver.findElement(By.id("image-selector-button ")).sendKeys("c:\\myFile.bmp");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('image-selector-button').style.display = 'none';");
```

Comment: Thank you gilly.  I tried this and confirmed that the display style for the element is set to block after executing that js command.  But WebDriver still returns this error when I try to sendKeys() to the element while it is in that state:                                org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element must be displayed to click (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer, thank you gilly!  The reason it was not working for me is that webDriver requires an element to be larger than 10px and the element I was interacting with was 280px x 0px.  Once I re-sized it via JavaScript I was able to interact in the manner you suggested.  Thanks again!